# Opacity of background picture in HTML

Tags: html, background-image, opacity

Can I change the `opacity` of the background picture in `HTML`?

I found one solution online but in it a box was added on top of the background picture and the box's opacity was changed hence changing the opacity of the background picture.

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://placekitten.com/g/300/100");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.div1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="div1">
    <p> HERE THE TEXT AND OTHER PARAGRAPH WILL BE ADDED.</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the opacity with CSS on the image itself, however it will change the opacity for the child elements too.

So I would do it as following, create a wrapper element with position relative. Then add an extra background div that will stretch over the relative wrapper, functioning as a background image for the content div. Now you can change opacity on the image.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.wrapper .background {
  background-image: url("http://uploads.refuzion.nl/stock.jpeg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: 0.3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.div1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: 'Rubik', sans-serif;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="background"></div>
<div class="div1">
  <p> HERE THE TEXT AND OTHER PARAGRAPH WILL BE ADDED.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

That being said the code you've included with your answer already functions as expected and basically does the same result as my solution.

Answer (score -1):

Use this CSS for that

```css
img {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: refrain from posting screenshots of code

Comment: Remove the image of the code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).